# Why does transmuting a f64 into u64 and then back into f64 result in a different value?

Tags: hash, rust, key, unsafe

I have a unique scenario where I want to use `f64` as a key in a `HashMap`. In particular I know the `f64` will never be `NaN` and I can tolerate `f64`s that should be equal, but are not. So I `transmute()` the `f64` to `u64`. However, when I pull the `u64` out the `HashMap` and `transmute()` it back to a `f64` it is a different value. Code below and on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69caeba17581278713d28fcd1ed56043).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let x = 5.0;
    let y: u64 = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(x) };
    let x: f64 = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(y) };
    println!("y: {}, x: {}", y, x);
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert(y, 8);
    for (y, _) in &hash {
        let x: f64 = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(y) };
        println!("y: {}, x: {}", y, x);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write `for (y, _) in &hash`, `y` will be a *reference* to the key, which you will then transmute to a meaningless float.

Should you write `for (&y, _) in &hash` or use `*y`, you'd get the expected value.

Transmuting the wrong thing is why one should never infer the types when using `transmute`, and should always avoid `transmute`. In particular, for this specific transformation, there are the safe methods [`f64::to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.to_bits) and [`f64::from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.from_bits). An even more idiomatic way would be to use a `HashMap<FloatWrapper, Value>` where `FloatWrapper` implements `Ord`.